# Getting name of an object from list in Map

Tags: r, list, function, mapping

Given the following data:

```
list_A <- list(data_cars = mtcars,
               data_air = AirPassengers,
               data_list = list(A = 1,
                                B = 2))
```

I would like to print names of objects available across `list_A`.

## Example:

```
Map(
    f = function(x) {
        nm <- deparse(match.call()$x)
        print(nm)
        # nm object is only needed to properly name flat file that may be
        # produced within Map call
        if (any(class(x) == "list")) {
            length(x) + 1
        } else {
            length(x) + 1e6
            saveRDS(object = x,
                    file = tempfile(pattern = make.names(nm), fileext = ".RDS"))
        }
    },
    list_A
)
```

returns:

```
[1] "dots[[1L]][[1L]]"
[1] "dots[[1L]][[2L]]"
[1] "dots[[1L]][[3L]]"
$data_cars
NULL

$data_air
NULL

$data_list
[1] 3
```

### Desired results

I would like to get:

```
`data_cars`
`data_air`
`data_list`
```

## Update

Following the comments, I have modified the example to make it more reflective of my actual needs which are:

- While using `Map` to iterate over `list_A` I'm performing some operations on each element of the list
- Periodically I want to create a flat file with name reflecting name of object that was processed
- In addition to `list_A`, there are also `list_B`, `list_C` and so forth. Therefore, I would like to avoid calling `names(list)` inside the function `f` of the `Map` as I will have to modify it *n* number of times. The solution I'm looking to find should lend itself for:

  ```
  Map(function(l){...}, list_A)
  ```

  So I can later replace `list_A`. It does not have to rely on `Map`. Any of the [apply](/questions/tagged/apply) functions would do; same applied to [purrr](/questions/tagged/purrr)-based solutions.

---

## *Alternative example*

```
do_stuff <- function(x) {
    nm <- deparse(match.call()$x)
    print(nm)
    # nm object is only needed to properly name flat file that may be
    # produced within Map call
    if (any(class(x) == "list")) {
        length(x) + 1
    } else {
        length(x) + 1e6
        saveRDS(object = x,
                file = tempfile(pattern = make.names(nm), fileext = ".RDS"))
    }
}

Map(do_stuff, list_A)
```

*As per the notes below, I want to avoid having to modify `do_stuff` function as I will be looking to do:*

- `Map(do_stuff, list_A)`
- `Map(do_stuff, list_B)`
- `Map(do_stuff, list_...)`

Comment: What's wrong with `names(list_A)` ?

Comment: @RonakShah I need name inside `Map` as in my actual function I'm creating flat files from some objects in the list and I need object name to name flat file.

Comment: It's not clear to me why `names(list_A)` isn't an option for you. Could you build a better example to show why?

Comment: What about `attributes(Map(.))[[1]]`?

Comment: Are you asking how to iterate over both the names and that data? If that's the case you can use `purrr::map2(list_A, names(list_A), ~ .y)` and access the corresponding data element via `.x`. If this isn't what you're looking for I am also confused as to why `names(list_A)` isn't what you are looking for.

Comment: @MHammer I also think that OP might want to iterate over `list_A` keeping names. I'd just suggest to avoid to use external packages (especially `purrrr` which have a ton of dependencies) when a `base` solution is equivalent. For instance `Map(function(x,y) dosomethingWithNamesAndValues, list_A, names(list_A))`.

Comment: Agreed. I misread his function call to be `map` not `Map` which is why I made the jump to use `purrr` instead of it's base counterpart.

Comment: @jaySf Would you care to provide full example? It may work, I just want to avoid having to call `Map` twice as it's quite a lot that is packed there.

Comment: @Konrad `test <- Map(do_stuff, list_A); attributes(test)[[1]]`?

Comment: Yes, but how I ensure that the flat file produced within `Map()` carries value from `attributes(test)[[1]]`.I would have to write separate function and rename them.

Comment: `Map` will not pass along names of list elements. So I agree that you probably need to do something like, `do_stuff <- function(x, nm) { do stuff }; Map(do_stuff, list, names(list))`.

Comment: Or just pass `names(list)` and get `list` from parent environment. Here you don't need `Map`, `lapply` will work fine, you could also investigate functions `purr::imap` and `purr::lmap` for compact syntax

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper, yes but that requires changing `do_stuff` depending on the object name, which is what OP specifically does not want.

Comment: @Axeman Correct; this said, I have nothing against some meta programming automatic generation of proper `do_stuff` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this work ?

```
list_A2 <- Map(list, x = list_A,nm = names(list_A) )
trace(do_stuff, quote({ nm <- x$nm;  x<- x$x}), at=3)
Map(do_stuff, list_A2)
```

Comment: Nice use of `trace` and `quote`.

Comment: Could you explain why `at=3`? I want to understand why you were looking at third step of the function.

Comment: I just want to do the magic after `nm <- deparse(match.call()$x)`, else my `nm <- x$nm` will be overwritten.  `nm <- deparse(match.call()$x)` still happens, but it's overwritten by my code. For some reason I don't understand, `at=1` and `at=2` seem to do the same thing, so to put our code at the right place we need `at=3`. Does it make sense ?

Comment: Yes, Thanks very much for the explanation.

Answer (score 4):

We could wrap it into a function, and do it in two steps:

```
myFun <- function(myList){
  # do stuff
  res <- Map(
    f = function(x) {
      #do stuff
      head(x)
    },
    myList)

  # write to a file, here we might add control
  # if list is empty do not output to a file
  for(i in names(res)){
    write.table(res[[ i ]], file = paste0(i, ".txt"))
  }
}

myFun(list_A)
```

Comment: I was thinking that in case of `for`-based solution I could use `get` from on `list` and do things like that with `seq_along` `names`. It will work, just takes me away from beautiful `Map(do_stuff, list_...)` syntax. I will accept if there is no alternative. I think I may be asking for impossible; unless there would be away to make `do_stuff` search parent environment, find mother object of `x` and then subset names using `"dots[[n]][[n]]"` string but that's very fiddly for something that *IMHO* should be simpler.

Comment: or `lapply(names(res), function(i) write.table(res[[i]], file = paste0(i, ".txt"))` instead of the loop.

Comment: @Axeman That's what I was thinking, too, but their real `Map` might be more complex.

Comment: @Konrad, I think you'll find that traversing the environments will be more pain than it is worth. I usually manipulate and save in two steps, like shown here.